# Java BFS - What should I change if I wanted to move diagonally?

Tags: java, matrix, breadth-first-search

I'm looking at this code and I don't really know how I can implement diagonal moves.
I've tried changing the possible movements, but I don't know how should I do that.
The expected result is that the code looks for the shortest path moving diagonally when possible to reduce the total cost.
Sorry for the length of the code and thank you.

```
{
    // (x, y) represents matrix cell coordinates
    // dist represent its minimum distance from the source
    int x, y, dist;

    Node(int x, int y, int dist) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dist = dist;
    }
};

class Main
{
    // M x N matrix
    private static final int M = 10;
    private static final int N = 10;

    // Possible movements
    private static final int row[] = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
    private static final int col[] = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };

    // Function to check if it is possible to go to position (row, col)
    private static boolean isValid(int mat[][], boolean visited[][], int row, int col)
    {
        return (row >= 0) && (row < M) && (col >= 0) && (col < N)
                        && mat[row][col] == 1 && !visited[row][col];
    }

    // Find Shortest Possible Route
    // cell (i, j) to cell (x, y)
    private static void BFS(int mat[][], int i, int j, int x, int y)
    {
        // construct a matrix to keep track of visited cells
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[M][N];

        // create an empty queue
        Queue<Node> q = new ArrayDeque<>();

        // mark source cell as visited and enqueue the source node
        visited[i][j] = true;
        q.add(new Node(i, j, 0));

        // stores length of longest path from source to destination
        int min_dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        // run till queue is not empty
        while (!q.isEmpty())
        {
            // pop front node from queue and process it
            Node node = q.poll();

            // (i, j) represents current cell and dist stores its
            // minimum distance from the source
            i = node.x;
            j = node.y;
            int dist = node.dist;

            // if destination is found, update min_dist and stop
            if (i == x && j == y)
            {
                min_dist = dist;
                break;
            }

            // check for all 4 possible movements from current cell
            // and enqueue each valid movement
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                // check if it is possible to go to position
                // (i + row[k], j + col[k]) from current position
                if (isValid(mat, visited, i + row[k], j + col[k]))
                {
                    // mark next cell as visited and enqueue it
                    visited[i + row[k]][j + col[k]] = true;
                    q.add(new Node(i + row[k], j + col[k], dist + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        if (min_dist != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.print("The shortest path from source to destination " +
                                     "has length " + min_dist);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Destination can't be reached from given source");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe narrow down your question so that we can actually answer it? As it stands this is just a big code dump that we have to spend a lot of time analyzing and figuring out what does what and why.

Comment: You will have to add that movements to the movements arrays (`row` and `col`) and increase the range of `k` to the new limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A movement matrix look like

```
(-1, -1) (-1,  0) (-1,  1)
( 0, -1) ( r,  c) ( 0,  1)
( 1, -1) ( 1,  0) ( 1,  1)
```

Where

```
r - is the current row
c - is the current column
```

The values represent the amount that need to be added to the current position to get there

Base on this you can extend your functionality